# Laravel 5: How to pass parameters to inner where query

Tags: laravel-5

I've following query:

```
$visible = array(1,2,3);
$views = DB::table('ims_view')
    ->Where(function($query) {
        $query->where('iv_status', 1)->whereIn('id', $visible);
    })->orderBy('iv_name', 'asc')->get();
```

> Error: Undefined variable: visible

How to pass the variabnle to inner where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use the variable you want passed into the scope like so:
**use ($visible)**

```
`$views = DB::table('ims_view')
    ->Where(function($query) use ($visible){
           $query->where('iv_status', 1)
                  ->whereIn('id', $visible);
            })->orderBy('iv_name', 'asc')->get();`
```